# JAR file not visible in Java Request sampler of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using JAVA Request sample in Jmeter to do performance testing of my Selenium TestNG script.

I have created JAR file of my selenium project using maven plugin :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>test-jar</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
```

Kept JAR file under Jmeter/lib/ext folder.

Create Java request sample in Jmeter and check JAR files in Java request Class name but JAR file not reflected.

Also added Selenium Java JAR & Selenium standalone JAR files in Jmeter/lib folder.

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem when i compiled the jar with a newer version of java. JVM is 1.7 (jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.7.0_75) and jar made with 1.8 for example. Try using your java -version level for compileing the jar.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you intent to use Java Request Sampler your class should inherit from [AbstractJavaSamplerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/AbstractJavaSamplerClient.html) class and override `runTest` method. Something like:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient;
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext;

   public class Mytest extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient {

       @Override
       public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext context) {
       //your Selenium code here
       return null;
   }
   ```
2. If your tests are in [JUnit](http://junit.org/) format you can use [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) Sampler instead. Just put your jars under /lib/junit folder of your JMeter installation and JMeter should pick them up. See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) guide for comprehensive information on the integration
3. Are you aware of the [WebDriver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which provides Selenium integration almost out of the box?

Remember that you need to **restart JMeter** after adding or updating any .jar in its classpath or installing a plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware about configuration you have suggested and i tried it. But my query is related to Selenium TestNG, can i use Selenium TestNG script in Java Request Sampler or its only provide the Selenium script or pure Java script? I am aware about how to create JAR of the class file and where to keep it but my script is in TestNG and its JAR file is not visible in Java request sampler which i kept under jmeter/lib/ext folder for Java request sampler. Please let me know TestNG script is compatible with Java request sampler of Jmeter or not?

Comment: Read attentively. If your class extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient and overrides runTest() method - it'll work.